# How to create a file and its parent directories in one method call?

Tags: c#, file-io, refactoring

I want to create a file that is in specific directory.
For example: C:\x\y\z\aTextFile.txt

For this operation, I have to  create the directory to create file.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\x\y\z\");
File.Create(@"C:\x\y\z\aTextFile.txt");
```

But I really wonder that I can do this operation in single line of code.

Any help and idea will be greately appreciated.

Comment: Why is it so important to reduce this to one using a .Net framework specific method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know, there is no File creation method that create the directory at the same time in the .NET framework.

If the pattern "Directory check/creation, then file creation" is repeated a lot in your code, you have to implement it in a method.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: Add a function

```
void MySingleLineOfCodeFunction(string path, string filename)
{
    Directory.Createdirectory(path);
    File.Create(filename).Dispose();
}
```

and then use a single line of code:

```
MySingleLineOfCodeFunction(@"C:\x\y\z\", "a.txt");
```

What I am trying to say is that there is no difference between code.
Some of it is written by the Microsoft guys, while other by us, normal people. But the computers don't make a difference. :)

Comment: I have a method like this but I want to reduce  this two line of code to single line if it is possible

Comment: You did reduce it to a single line, by combining it in to a method. There is no difference between your method calling those two API calls and some Microsoft function that calls the two API calls. You still MUST do two calls, one for the directory, one for the file.

Comment: I  think there is a way to  do this with  built-in c# but there is no way np :)

Comment: Sorry I was responding to ibrah, not you. I was trying to defend your point.

Comment: I know method extraction but I just wonder is there a built-in way.

Comment: So we can say there is no way to do this except than method extraction :) sorry  guys

Comment: Please fix the sample code provided to use the parameters instead of the hard coded string.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no there is no single line of code to do what you want.

Why? Because even if we do so by some Microsoft inbuilt function, internally it will be calling two methods. One for Directory creation and other for file creation.

However you can reduce your lines of code by making them into a method and call it in a single line as Petar Ivanov said

**OR**

You can create a static extension method. This way you can use it at other places without creating instance. (Reduced your one line where instance is created).

Comment: Since File is a static type you won't be able to create extension methods for File.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the answer from @Petar_Ivanov, to work out the parent directory based on the file path, thought it may be useful to others who might want a similar function.

```
    public void CreateFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            var parent = Directory.GetParent(filePath);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(parent.FullName);
            File.Create(filePath).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating a file, no, the directory has to exist. Even with Visual Basic's file friendly classes, you still have to create the directories first. What is interesting is that moving will create the folder.

From CreateFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

> **Directories**
>
> An application cannot create a directory by using
>   CreateFile, therefore only the OPEN_EXISTING value is valid for
>   dwCreationDisposition for this use case. To create a directory, the
>   application must call CreateDirectory or CreateDirectoryEx

Comment: +1. You beat me to it :) This is not a limitation of the .NET framework, but it is a limitation the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly in my code blocks;
I handle folder existence right before file create parts.

```
public void CheckCreatePath(fileName)
{
    string filePath = Directory.GetParent(fileName).ToString();
    if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
}
```

and just use

```
CheckCreatePath("C:\\TEMP\\TESTPath\\myFile.txt");
```

in your code block.

Comment: Does this work if  `\TEMP` does not exit? The question says "parent directories".